# What is a simple way to receive SNMP traps in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, snmp, snmp4j, scala-dispatch

I'd love it if there is an awesome native Scala library for SNMP like there is [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/About) for HTTP but I can't find one. Is there one? Baring that, should I use a Java library like [SNMP4J](http://www.snmp4j.org)? What I want to do is so simple that it almost seems like overkill: I just want to listen on a given port for SNMP messages (which will always be in the same format) and send them on to an actor.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple googling I found this
http://code.google.com/p/snmpbulk/

Still requires snmp4j underneath though. And I also dont like SNMP4J but I agree with you that there are not simple alternatives. Good luck in your search.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice start. Unfortunately the GPL license means that we won't be able to use it here at work.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question, and you've probably long moved on... but I had the same problem in that I wanted to use Scala for SNMP.  Well, I created my own DSL: [SNMP4S](https://github.com/barnesjd/snmp4s/).  It is also built on top of SNMP4J, but I've designed the library such that there will be no compile-time linkages to SNMP4J so it can be changed out later if needed.